# DIY USB Mass Storage Tutorial

Tags: usb, memory, flash

I was just wondering if there was a tutorial anywhere on how to make your own USB Flash Drive and I don't mean take apart a USB and put the guts into something else, I mean put together the flash memory and controller.

Comment: Your title should be "DIY USB Mass storage tutorial" because you are specifically asking for a tutorial on how make your own flash drive. A question about making your own USB gadgets has been asked a while ago.

Comment: @bpijls I have changed the title.

Answer (score 13):

Dean Camera has written a USB stack for the AVR.  It includes a mass storage driver.

http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php

Comment: LUFA is very good.  And the AVR USB chips are getting better and better.  If you prefer to develop on Linux or OSX, LUFA on an AVR is a good choice.  If you're Windows, then look at the PIC development environment. The low-end PIC USB chips have more features and are easier to use than the low-end AVR USB chips, but you really can only develop for them on Windows.

Comment: Just an update about developing with PICs.  The new Microchip IDE, MPLAB X (which is still in beta) is based on NetBeans and allows PIC development on any of the major platforms (Windows/MAC/Linux).

Answer (score 7):

A question about general USB devices was asked [a while ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267/id-like-to-learn-how-to-make-my-own-usb-gadgets/274#274), but you are specifically referring to a USB mass storage device (MSD)

Jan Axelson (from http://janaxelson.com) has written a book about it: http://janaxelson.com/mass_storage.htm

Comment: Um, that link goes to a luxury clothing retailer... Not sure that's where it's supposed to go?

Answer (score 3):

You could base it on this project of mine:

http://www.leonheller.com/usb

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the easiest way is to use an AT90USB or LPC1343. The latter has mass-storage device firmware stored in ROM so you only need to supply some details for the device descriptor and 2 or 3 Flash access procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider the Cypress FX2.  It's a Hi-Speed USB chip that comes with Mass Storage Driver support.  Dunno about any tutorials for it, but it's a pretty popular chip.

Answer (score 1):

How about a good book on how usb works?

- [USB Complete - Jan Axelson](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm)

Then when you start to program, you know how things are supposed to work...